# How to strip emails only from file with names and spaces

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have this file name emaillist.txt:

```
CallMePink@newmail.com
BabyNavou@mailpost.gr
Ilias Magkakos imagkakos@badmail.com
Nick Pipshow NickTheGreek@mail.tr.gr
Don Quixote Windmill@mail.gr 
Crazy Priest SeVaftise@hotmail.com
Fishroe Salad fishroesalad@mail.com
TaPanta Ola OlaMaziLeme@mail.gr
Laertis George I8aki@mail.gr
Thiseas Sparrow Pirates@mail.gr
Black Dreamer SupaHacka@mail.com
Callme Daddy xyz@mail.com
Aggeliki Lykolouli FwsStoTounel@Traino.pourxetai
Kompinadoros Yannnnis YannisWith4N@rolf.com
Serafino Titamola Ombrax@mail.gr
Joe Hard Soft@Butter.gr
Bond James MyNameIsBond@JamesBond.com
Endof Text EndOfLine@mail.com
```

and I would like to leave only the emails from file and remove all the first names and last names.

Comment: Why do you think a regular expression is the solution here? Unless you need to cope with email addresses which contain spaces, just split on space and fetch the last token.  `awk '{ print $NF }' emaillist.txt`

Comment: open in excel, delimited, choose `@` as a delimiter, then delete column(s) A and everything before the `@`.  Should be left with a column of everything happening after the `@`  Then save that excel file as a text file.  No excel, use openoffice in windows or libreoffice in linux

Comment: and my email better not be in that list and i better not get a new wave of emails telling me how to lose weight or grow a certain body part

Comment: This looks like a ["hack the box"](https://forum.hackthebox.eu/) challenge.

Comment: @ron please. This is trivial to do with proper text parsing tools, why in the world would you use something as cumbersome and needlessly complicated as Excel? What you describe can be done with `awk -F'@' '{print $NF}'`. It's not actually what the OP asks for though anyway.

Comment: @terdon please.  Like I actually care.  didn't know it was heresy to say *excel* in the comments

Comment: @ron My apologies. Reading that "please" in your comment made me realize how aggressive mine was. I didn't mean it to be, sorry. I'm just flabbergasted by the idea that you would use as difficult and complex a tool as Excel (or equivalent) when it's so easy to do with awk or sed or any number of native tools. In any case, what you describe would leave just the domain, the question needs to get the entire email. So you'd want to open it as space-delimited, not `@`-delimited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, since the email address seems to always be the last space-delimited field of each line, you could just do:

```
awk '{print $NF}' < emaillist.txt
```

Or if there's never any whitespace after the email address, delete everything up to the last whitespace on each line:

```
sed 's/.*[[:space:]]//' < emaillist.txt
```

To retrieve all the whitespace-delimited words that contain at least one `@` character, that could be (with GNU `grep` or compatible):

```
grep -o '[^[:space:]]*@[^[:space:]]*' < emaillist.txt
```

Comment: `"my address"@contoso.com` is a syntactically valid address according to [RFC 5322](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.4.1) (including the double quotes), so splitting on whitespace isn't always safe

Comment: @roaima, yes, you'll notice I worded my answer especially so as not to imply an email address may not contain spaces.

Comment: Mmm. I didn't see that in your answer

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I agree it's useful to point out that one can't make the general assumption that email addresses can't contain spaces, which I didn't and which you did. I'm saying that for instance I didn't say: "extracts all email addresses", but extracts words  containing at least one `@`, (which may not extract email adresses properly or extract things that are not valid email address if the input was not as tamed as in the OP's sample).